# Rails, highcharts how to show x axis labels

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have a dashboard with highcharts API. The graph functions correctly with the data but I can't get the x-axis labels to show in the view. Instead I get 0, 1, 2, 3 etc...

[image: Column Chart]

```
....xAxis: {
                categories: [],
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify',
                    style: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },.....

....series: [{
           name: 'Number of Notes By Class',
           data: <%= @data %> 
          }]
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
def dashboard
  @data = Note.getData()
end
```

Model:

```
def self.getData
    data = []
    self.subject_types.each do |type|
      data << self.type_count(type)
    end
    data
  end

  private

  def self.subject_types
    pluck(:subject_type).uniq
  end
```

I'm trying to get the labels to show up from the table automatically. Any ideas on how to do this? I have been trying for ages. Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
<script>
 $(function () {


        $('#notes_chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                [0, '#2a2a2b'],
                [1, '#3e3e40']
         ]
      },

            },
            title: {
                text: 'Total Notes By Class Module'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Notes Table'
            },
            xAxis: {
                    categories: [],
                        title: {
                            text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify',
                    style: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Number',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify',
                    style: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: <%= @series_data %>
        });
    });
</script>





def dashboard
      @series_data = []
      @notes = Note.select("id, subject_type, COUNT(*) AS total").group("id, subject_type")
      # Collect series data that will be show
      @notes.group_by(&:subject_type).each do |k, v|
        @series_data << { name: k.titleize, data: [v.size] }   
      end
    end
```

Comment: your  categories: [] are empty so highcharts taking 0,1,2 as label. fill the category array . It would be helpful if you can post your json response/data here.

Comment: Can anyone help with this? All I want to do is get the labels from the table and have them automatically rendered on the chart along with the data. How do I do this? Thanks.